# Why do they use a different tap for filtered water instead of the regular tap?

Tags: plumbing, water, water-filtration

I'm talking about the kitchen sink. Why not just connect the filters to the regular tap?

Answer (score 6):

The kitchen sink is used for various other purposes than getting a glass of water to drink. So you don't want to be wasting the filter when doing your dishes.

Answer (score 3):

Water filters that remove chemicals and such require significant [contact time](http://www.watertreatmentguide.com/activated_carbon_filtration.htm) with the filter media (media is often [activated carbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activated_carbon)) to be effective.

This contact time requirement restricts flow significantly, so much that you would not be able to efficiently perform other common tasks that are normally done in the kitchen sink: rinse/wash dishes, wash fruits and veggies, fill pots with water, wash hands, etc.

Comment: So how does the whole house filter can deal with it?

Comment: Whole-house units are merely sediment filters, no"contact time" needed; However; even those cause a noticeable and measurable restriction to flow.